# Gyro Accelerometer Complementary Filter

Tags: math, rotation, arduino, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am trying to create an artificial horizon using a 3 axis gyro and accelerometer (MPU6050).

To prevent gyro drift I am using a complementary filter that mixes the gryo and accelerometer values together.

My problem is due to the nature of the formula I am using to mix the values, when the value reaches an extent of 0 or 360 degrees the value will count up or down in increments until it reaches the correct angle.

For example:
I start on a flat surface my comp filter value is 180. 
I then rotate the unit so it is counting upwards to 360 degrees.
When the unit gets to 360 degrees I keep rotating in the same direction.
Because the accYangle value has flipped from 360 to 0 my comp filter value will count down until it reaches 0 degrees.

This is a problem because my onscreen artificial horizon will rotate 360 degrees backwards before continuing in the right direction.

I have sat and pondered for days to come up with a solution of how I could fix this problem looking at ways to change the formula but maths is not one of my strengths and I have come to the conclusion I need help from greater minds.

```
  // Read raw values from MPU6050
  accelgyro.getMotion6(&accX, &accY, &accZ, &gyroX, &gyroY, &gyroZ);

  // Convert accelerometer raw values to degrees
  double accXangle = (atan2(accY, accZ) + PI) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double accYangle = (atan2(accX, accZ) + PI) * RAD_TO_DEG;

  // Convert raw gyro values to degrees per second
  double gyroXrate = (double)gyroX / 131.0;
  double gyroYrate = -((double)gyroY / 131.0);

  // Calculate angles using complementary filter
  compAngleX.myDouble = (0.93 * (compAngleX.myDouble + (gyroXrate * (double)(micros() - timer) / 1000000))) + (0.07 * accXangle);
  compAngleY.myDouble = (0.93 * (compAngleY.myDouble + (gyroYrate * (double)(micros() - timer) / 1000000))) + (0.07 * accYangle);

  timer = micros();

  // Write values to serial port
  for (int i=1; i <= 4; i++){
    Serial.write(255);
  }
  Serial.write(compAngleX.myChars, sizeof(double));
  Serial.write(compAngleY.myChars, sizeof(double));
```

Comment: I see this was early 2014 - Did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope... im sure its an easy maths trick but im no good a math :)